# How to ensure ModalPopupExtender only shows when validation is successful?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

How do I setup the `ModalPopupExtender` to not show when the validation on the page fails? I have a `RequiredFieldValidator` on a textbox. On Submit, I would like to show the `ModalPopupExtender` ONLY if validation is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set it up so that I can control it on the server side. This way, I was able to run the validation first before showing/hiding the ModalPopupExtender

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly straightforward.  In your Page_Load or PreRender code, try something like this:

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
   myModalExtender.Show();
}
```

Comment: The ModalPopupExtender by default shows on the client side when the control specified by the TargetControlId is clicked